# Make sum of all table row field in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have 4 tables, in this all tables have 3 rows[record] and 3 column[field]  field like Date Name Total. This table like below:

First Table

```
   Date                  Name                      Total
 2012-11-07             Manoj                       10
 2012-11-08             Ganesh                       4
 2012-11-09             Sri                         30
```

Second Table

```
  Date                   Name                      Total
2012-11-07               Raju                         5
2012-11-08               ggg                          3
2012-11-09               Shshi                       30
```

Third Table

```
 Date                   Name                      Total
2012-11-07              Ram                         2
2012-11-08               gm                         5
2012-11-09             Shsse                       30
```

I need Output Like following type in PHP

```
Date          Total
2012-11-07      17
2012-11-08      12
2012-11-09      90
```

It  should display all total in between date in PHP

Comment: Why are the tables separate... they appear to store the same data types?

Comment: Are you inserting data into table? You can union all and then SUM total group by date. Can you post your exported table so i can write query.

Comment: why are you using 4 separate tables? Is it necessary to keep you data in such manner?

Comment: I am not inserting table @VibhaJ. I just doing sum total group by date. I need PHP script to get the report. this is my code. Pls help me: $sql9=mysql_query("select Date, sum(Total) as Total (from select Date, Total from kundapurper where Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' union all select Date, Total from udupiper where Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' union all select Date, Total from honnaper where Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' ) src group by Date WHERE Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' order by Date DESC "); if(!$sql9) { print" Report Could Not Success, Try Again"; exit(); }

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION ALL`:

```
select date, sum(total) AllTotal
from
(
  select date, total
  from table1
  union all
  select date, total
  from table2
  union all
  select date, total
  from table3
) src
group by date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fec0/2)

Or you might be able to use a `LEFT JOIN` similar to this:

```
select t1.date, sum(t1.total + t2.total + t3.total) AllTotal
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.date = t2.date
left join table3 t3
  on t1.date = t3.date
group by t1.date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fec0/4)

Comment: @GaneshJogii happy to help, if this answer is helpful to you be sure to accept it via the checkmark on the left.  It will help future visitors to the site and you get rep for accepting. :)

Comment: hi @bluefeet. In SQL it worked perfectly. but while write in PHP i get error

Comment: I need this output display in PHP table. this is my code: $sql9=mysql_query("select `Date`, sum(Total) as Total (from  select `Date`, `Total`
  from kundapurper where Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'
  union all
  select `Date`, Total
  from udupiper where Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'

  union all
  select `Date`, Total
  from honnaper where Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'


  
) src
group by Date 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' order by Date DESC  ");

if(!$sql9)
{
print" Report Could Not Success, Try Again";
exit();
}

Comment: @GaneshJogii I am not familiar with PHP to be able to debug that for you. My suggestion would be to post another question regarding the PHP error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE, SUM(Total) totalSum
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM TableB
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM tableC
) s
GROUP BY DATE
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62e50/1)

Comment: this sql code worked in SQL. however, i need this code work in php. how can i do this. this my code: $sql9=mysql_query("select `Date`, sum(Total) as Total (from  select `Date`, `Total`
  from kundapurper where Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'
  union all
  select `Date`, Total
  from udupiper where Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'

  union all
  select `Date`, Total
  from honnaper where Date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'


  
) src
group by Date  ");

if(!$sql9)
{
print" Report Could Not Success, Try Again";
exit();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
select tbl1.date,sum(total)
from tbl1,
tbl2,
tbl3
where tbl1.date = tbl2.date and
tbl2.date = tbl3.date
group by tbl1.date;
```

Comment: Can you add some comment to your code? It helps understanding it and why you suggested it on first place.

Comment: can u give me code in PHP if possilbe. it will be very helpful if u posting code in PHP @Yaroslav