# SQL output shows in PHP in table format

Tags: php, sum, report

I have 4 tables, in this all tables have 3 rows[record] and 3 column[field] field like Date Name Total. This table like below:

First Table

```
Date                  Name                      Total
2012-11-07             Manoj                       10
2012-11-08             Ganesh                       4
2012-11-09             Sri                         30
```

Second Table

```
Date                   Name                      Total
2012-11-07               Raju                         5
2012-11-08               ggg                          3
2012-11-09               Shshi                       30
```

Third Table

```
Date                   Name                      Total
2012-11-07              Ram                         2
2012-11-08               gm                         5
2012-11-09             Shsse                       30
```

I need output like following type in PHP:

```
 Date          Total
 2012-11-07      17
 2012-11-08      12
 2012-11-09      90
```

It should display all total in between date in PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make sum of all table row field in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624915/make-sum-of-all-table-row-field-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a SQL Statement that will merge all of the tables to create a single table with the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT DATE, SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL
FROM
(
SELECT DATE, TOTAL FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE, TOTAL FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE, TOTAL FROM Table3
) AS AllTables
WHERE Date BETWEEN '1 JAN 2012' AND '13 JAN 2012'
GROUP BY Date
```

This result can be displayed in php as you would any other table

Comment: ok Richard Vivian Its Successfully Done in php but i need it shows in between date, is it possible ? please write code here like Date Between 2012-11-10 AND 2012-11-01 thank you

Comment: ok Richard Vivian Its Successfully Done in php but i need it shows in between date, is it possible ? please write code here like Date Between 2012-11-10 AND 2012-11-01 order by desc in php only thank you

Comment: See the edited SQL above for the added where clause.  Depending on the SQL DB you are connecting to you can create the above SQL as a view and select from the view where the dates are between your Start and end dates.  May make PHP Select simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an inner join between the 3 tables by the date, and making a sum over the totals (over a new field).

For example

```
SELECT t1.date, (t1.total + t2.total + t3.total) AS final_total
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.date=t2.date
INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.date=t3.date
GROUP BY t1.date
```

Comment: An inner join will only work if Table1 has all of the dates available.  If there are dates in tables 2 and 3 that are not in table 1, these totals will be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the tables are dateslist,datelist2 and datelist3, Then use the following code:

```
SELECT 
dateslist.`Date`,SUM(dateslist.`Total`+datelist2.`Total`+datelist3.`Total`) 
FROM 
`dateslist` 
JOIN 
datelist2 on dateslist.Date=datelist2.Date 
JOIN 
datelist3 ON datelist2.Date=datelist3.Date GROUP BY dateslist.Date
```